# Sent target back to starting position if target not geting damage or reaches max allowed distance from starting position

Tags: unity-game-engine

i have problem with trying to sent target back to his start position if damage wasn't dealt or if he reaches max allowed distance from starting position.
Now when target reaching max allowed distance he just freeze and waiting untill Couroutine ends count time. but i want he return immediately..

Here is the code im using.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.AI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(NavMeshAgent))]
public class DFieldOfView : MonoBehaviour
{

    NavMeshAgent agent;
    public Transform startingPoint;

    public float maxAttackDistance = 3;
    public float maxAllowedDistance = 10f;
    public float viewRadius;        // matymo laukas
    [Range(0, 360)]                                   // Range nuo iki
    public float viewAngle;        // matymo kampas
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask targetMask;                                                           
    public LayerMask obstacleMask;                                                         
    [SerializeField] private float rotatingSpeed = 20f;
    //[SerializeField] ParticleSystem fireEffect;

    [HideInInspector] public float dstToTarget;
    [HideInInspector] public List<Transform> visibleTargets = new List<Transform>();                 

    Transform targets;
    EnemyHealth health;

    private Animator anim;
    private new AudioSource audio;
    //private bool isShootReady = false;
    Vector3 dirToTarget;
    bool targetunset = true;
    //bool sound_playing = false;
    Quaternion rotation;

    public float totalDuration = 3f;
    public bool isDamageActivated = false;

    //public float SoundTime = 3f;

    void Start()
    {
        health = GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        //audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (isDamageActivated)
        {
            FindVisableTarget();
            StartCoroutine(AgroRoutine(targets));
        }
        Debug.Log("Damage was dealt: " + isDamageActivated);
    }

    void FindVisableTarget()                                                                                // Rasti matomus taikinius
    {
        visibleTargets.Clear();                                                                             // istrina lista
        Collider[] targetsInViewRadius = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, viewRadius, targetMask); // grazina visus taikinius kurie ieina i matymo lauka
        for (int i = 0; i < targetsInViewRadius.Length; i++)                                                // matomi tainkiniai
        {
            targets = targetsInViewRadius[i].transform;                                           // Taikiniai matymo lauke
            if (targetunset) { SetTarget(targets); }
            dirToTarget = (targets.position - transform.position).normalized;                               // kryptis i taikini
            if (Vector3.Angle(transform.forward, dirToTarget) < viewAngle / 2)                              //  ar taikinys yra matomumo zonoi
            {
                dstToTarget = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targets.position);                       //distancija iki taikinio
                if (!Physics.Raycast(transform.position, dirToTarget, dstToTarget, obstacleMask))           // nera jokiu kliuciu ir taikinys matomas
                {
                    Rotating();
                    visibleTargets.Add(targets);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //IEnumerator AgroRoutine(Transform target)
    //{
    //    float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, startingPoint.position);
    //    if (targets != null)
    //    {
    //        if ((transform.position - startingPoint.position).magnitude < maxAllowedDistance)
    //        {

    //            MoveTo(targets.position);
    //            anim.SetBool("isRuning", true);
    //            if (maxAttackDistance <= dstToTarget)
    //            {
    //                Debug.Log(dstToTarget);
    //                anim.SetBool("isAttacking", true);
    //            }
    //            else
    //            {
    //                anim.SetTrigger("idle");
    //            }
    //            Debug.Log("Target not null and in range");
    //        }
    //        else if ((transform.position - startingPoint.position).magnitude > maxAllowedDistance)
    //        {
    //            Debug.Log("Target null and/or out of range");
    //            yield return new WaitForSeconds(agroDuration);
    //            MoveTo(startingPoint.position);
    //            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
    //            anim.SetTrigger("idle");
    //        }
    //    }
    //}

    IEnumerator AgroRoutine(Transform target)
    {
        if (target != null)
        {
            MoveTo(targets.position);
            anim.SetBool("isRuning", true);
            if (maxAttackDistance >= dstToTarget)
            {
                Debug.Log("Attacking");
                agent.isStopped = true;
                anim.SetBool("isAttacking", true);
            }
            else
            {
                anim.SetTrigger("idle");
            }
            Debug.Log("Target not null and in range");

            totalDuration = 3f; // 3 seconds. You can change this to whatever you want
            float timer = 0;

            while (timer <= totalDuration)
            {
                // Check for maximum allowed distance
                float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, startingPoint.position);

                if (distance >= maxAllowedDistance || distance >= MonsterField.radius)
                    Return(startingPoint.position);
                Debug.Log("Distance more than allowed distance " + (distance > maxAllowedDistance || distance >= MonsterField.radius));
                // Your object can keep moving. Increment timer and check again on the next frame
                timer += Time.deltaTime;
                yield return null;
            }
        }

    }

    public void Return(Vector3 point)
    {
        MoveTo(point);
        anim.SetTrigger("idle");
    }

    IEnumerator DamageStopRoutine()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(totalDuration);
        isDamageActivated = false;
    }


    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Bullet")
        {
            isDamageActivated = true;  // damage activated

            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            TakeHP(BulletDamage.currentBulletDmg);
        }
        StartCoroutine(DamageStopRoutine());
    }

    public void MoveTo(Vector3 point)
    {
        agent.SetDestination(point);
    }

    public Vector3 DirFromAngle(float angleInDegrees, bool angleIsGlobal)
    {
        if (!angleIsGlobal)
        {
            angleInDegrees += transform.eulerAngles.y;
        }
        return new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(angleInDegrees * Mathf.Deg2Rad), 0, Mathf.Cos(angleInDegrees * Mathf.Deg2Rad));
    }

    public void SetTarget(Transform targets)
    {
        targetunset = false;
        dirToTarget = (targets.position - transform.position).normalized; // kryptis i taikini
        rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(dirToTarget);

        Invoke("UnsetTarget", 0.05f);
    }

    public void Rotating()
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * rotatingSpeed);
    }
    public void UnsetTarget()
    {
        targetunset = true;
    }

    //public void PlayingSound()
    //{
    //    audio.Play();
    //    sound_playing = true;
    //    Invoke("StoppingSound", SoundTime);
    //}

    //public void StoppingSound()
    //{
    //    audio.Stop();
    //    sound_playing = false;
    //}

    public void TakeHP(float dmg)
    {
        health.initialHP -= dmg;
        // hit animation
        anim.SetTrigger("hit");
        new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        anim.SetTrigger("idle");
        if (health.initialHP <= 0)
        {
            Die();
        }
    }

    void Die()
    {
        // animation
        anim.SetBool("isAttacking", false);
        anim.SetBool("isDied", true);
        Destroy(gameObject, 2f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Beyond max distance, set location to start, move 1 unit, distance is less than max, set location to target, move 1 unit,  distance beyond max...

Comment: Also, `Debug.Log("Target null and/or out of range")`, no, if the target is null, your coroutine terminates. Target has to be non null to reach this debug statement. You also calculate the distance, but never use it, opting to recalculate instead.

Comment: In your coroutine, you're using your passed argument. You're still using the class-scoped `targets` instead of `target`. You might have some issue where `targets` is being updated outside of the coroutine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit

You need to separate your movement logic from your stopping logic. Move your object normally, and use the coroutine for the stopping logic. I have reworked it based on your two criteria: time and distance.

```
IEnumerator AgroRoutine(Transform target)
{
    if (target != null)
        yield return break;

    float totalDuration = 3f; // 3 seconds. You can change this to whatever you want
    float timer = 0;

    while (timer <= totalDuration)
    {
        // Check for maximum allowed distance
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, startingPoint.position);

        if (distance > maxAllowedDistance)
            Return(startingPoint.position);

        // Your object can keep moving. Increment timer and check again on the next frame
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
}

public void Return (Vector3 point)
{
    MoveTo(point);
    anim.SetTrigger("idle");
}
```

---

### Old

You told the coroutine to wait 3 seconds before moving. Remove that line if you don't want that to happen.

```
public float agroDuration = 3f;

IEnumerator AgroRoutine(Transform target)
{
    ...
    else if ((transform.position - startingPoint.position).magnitude > maxAllowedDistance)
        {
            Debug.Log("Target null and/or out of range");
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(agroDuration);
            MoveTo(startingPoint.position);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
            anim.SetTrigger("idle");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well the problem im checking or damge was dealt with OnTriggerEnter and as long my bullet get Destoyed with collide and function updates with shooting only. I think i forgot to say. i want target start chasing on hit and if there is no more damage or he reach range limit he should back to starting position. :)

Comment: So, you're saying you have two conditions where the object will return: a timer and a maximum distance. Is that maximum distance traveled or a range?

Comment: Im starting move target OnTrigerEnter and becouse i dont have how to check if this trigger is false i can return him in starting position with out shooting to target once more so ... i dont realy know how it works this way, but seems when im shoot at target last time code goes to else statement and only then he going back to starting position. before i was trying to check lastShootTime(or damage) time lastShootTime = Time.time - lastShootTime; and every time i was shooting at target i was reseting lashootTime = 0; But thats not worked as well...im stuck 2 days on this one, already tryed alot

Comment: if I'am put this Coroutine logic to Update method, everything works fine, problem is this OnTriggerEnter, becouse it updates only if it gets triggered. In other words if he reaches then  if ((transform.position - startingPoint.position).magnitude < maxAllowedDistance) code just stops

Comment: THANK YOU ALOT!! it took a bit time to understand what did you mean :D (trying not use while loops becouse most of time crashing everything) but now it works :)

Comment: I'am Updated my code to show what im done. Added bool to check if damage was dealt and  one more Coroutine which activated when OnTriggerEnter activated and set bool to false after 3 seconds now so it lets activate my main coroutine in Update method. I dont realy know if its a good way to do this? I would like to hear your opinion :)

Comment: That looks good for now. No code will be perfect! I would apply some basic computer science principles later if and when you refactor. Look up SOLID and DRY principles on Wikipedia or Google.

Comment: Okay i will. Thank you :)

Comment: @Andrys Also, if this answer helped you, please choose it as a solution. You can also create your own answer and choose that as a solution if this one did not answer your question.